# Talend can't insert data in google cloud MySQL server

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, talend

I have a Talend job who insert data into a MySQL database on Google Cloud. Everything is ok, I manage to insert into log tables, except  when the job trys to insert into the target table with an tMySQLOutput component nothing happens and the job no longer responds.
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Can you provide more detail and error logs

Comment: No error message, just the job no longer moves forward and stops, no recording in the table.

Comment: You need to enable logging somewhere. You have not provided enough information.

Comment: Additionally to more details and error logs required in order to help, please specify if you are using Cloud SQL for your MySQL database or managing your own MySQL server on a Compute Engine instance.